# R//C circuit in time domain in Python

Tags: python, differential-equations

I am trying  to simulate a resistance in parallel of a capacitor with a varying current as input (current vs time, with a fast changing pace).
I want to do this in Python in the time domain using the exact solution of the equation. For validation, I put the differential equation in Simulink and compare the results.

**Equation resolution**

Equation:
dU / dt + U / (C*R) = I/C

Regular solution:
dU / dt + U / (C*R) = 0 => u(t) = k*exp(-t/(RC))+B

Particular solution:
I inject u(t) = k*exp(-t/(RC))+B in dU / dt + U / (C*R) = I/C
=> B = RI

Boundary condition: u(0) = Ureff giving: k = Ureff - RI

So general solution (work in discharge, charge, rest...): u(t)=(Ureff - RI) * exp(-t/(RC)) + RI

**Python**

- I determine the indexes where the current changes (if current passes from 5 to 10 at between index 9 and10, I  will save the index 10)
- I have a loop going through the time, with the equation:
  Utotal[i] = (Uref-R*I)*np.exp(-(time-offset_time) / (R*C))+R*I
- Uref and offset time are updated using the index where the current change (using a if). Uref takes as value the Utotal[i-1] and offset_time the value at time[i]. I=current[i]

**The issue**

It works well when the current does not change too fast (whatever R and C) or when R and C are below 1 and the current is changing fast. When I use the same current profile, but with values of R and C above 1, the Utotal[i] totally overshoots (it follows RI).

Here the voltage vs time at R=1 and C=1 (Python in red, Matlab in purple)
[image]
Here at R=1 and C=10
[image]

**Question**

Is it an issue with my solution of the equation (though it is working in some case) ?

Is it an issue with Uref taken at Utotal[i-1] when a change in current happens at i (and if the current changes too fast and with a high R*C, it does not work anymore) ?

Thank you

Comment: While it is difficult to provide detailed assistance, since you haven't provided any code.  The fact your python simulation seems to fail when the rate of current change increases, would seem to indicate your sampling rate needs to be higher.

Comment: Are you sure that the cases are the right way round? RC is the time constant; if it were large one would expect to get away with larger time steps and also that the current would change more slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

itprorh66 is correct, I interpolated all the input using a small sampling rate and it is much more accurate. it takes forever though and some parts are still not good, maybe the algo can be improved.
Then I used a formula found in the litterature using discretization: Urc(t) =Urc(t-1)*exp(-dt/(RC)) + R*I(t)*(1-exp(-dt/(RC)) and it works fast and as Simulink and close to measurements (now remains to understand how they found the formula above, not really clear besides it doing discretization)